# Android startup dialog remote data

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to show a dialog box with some remote data when the app starts (welcome message). for some reason this is not working. my code is this.

p.s. I have another progress type dialog which loads at start up. I'm trying to add this just after it.

Could anyone tell if this snippet is correct?

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.website.com/welcome.php");
try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", url));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
    //String url=response;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("My Title");
    builder.setMessage(response);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "CPE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
//Toast.makeText(this, "IOE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best test you can do what happend this code dos not work is :
try write e.printStackTrace(); between catch like :

```
try {
    ...
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to know waht happend.

also i think you get error that you cannot access io operation in ui thread, and you must call this method in other thread LIKE :

```
private void MyMethod() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.website.com/welcome.php");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", url));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        //String url=response;

        runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("My Title");
                    builder.setMessage(response);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
                    TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                }
            }
        );

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and when want to call this method :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MyMethod();
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, got the error. for some silly mistake the production code had welcome.txt instead of welcome.php and your code helped to get the error which was related to http not allowed(as im doing a POST request and .txt format).

Answer (score 0):

What is meaning of sentence "for some reason this is not working."? Am I correct when I say dialog doesn't appear?

1. There's problem with `httpclient.execute()`. If there is some problem with internet connection, dialog isn't created, because inception has been thrown. Can you see some warning/error in Logcat?
2. You can't do connection operations in UI Thread, otherwise `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say no - the snippet is not correct. Since API 11 all IO functions need to happen on a background thread. Background threads cannot touch the UI. As it currently stands you are executing an `HttpPost` within the same method as you are creating an `AlertDialog`. What you need to do is use an `AsyncTask` to (1) execute the post in the doInBackground method (2) return the result (3) use the returned result within the onPostExecute method to load your dialog (returning values from doInBackground will automatically send it to onPostExecute). onPostExecute runs on the UI thread so you can create an `AlertDialog` from that method.